# Should we adopt the AdE "Lingva Konsultejo"'s Qs & As?

Tags: discussion

The Akademio de Esperanto (AdE, [website](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademio_de_Esperanto)) seems to be *the* linguistic authority for the Esperanto language.

On [its wiki](https://akademio.info/akademio/), the Akademio publishes "elektitaj respondoj" (selected answers) of its "Lingva Konsultejo" (language consultation place) together with the corresponding questions. The "Lingva Konsultejo" seems to be a service of the Akademy, where they answer non-trivial questions sent by email or snail mail about Esperanto and its proper usage.

Here's the lists of their Q&A selections so far:

[Respondoj de la Konsultejo](http://akademio.info/akademio/index.php?title=Respondoj_de_la_Lingva_Konsultejo)

**Would these questions and answers be suitable for Esperanto Language Stack Exchange?**

If yes, should we **try to get these questions and answers onto Esperanto Language Stack Exchange?** If so, **how?**

- Should we ask the Akademy for permission to copy them here? (Of course with proper attribution and link back to the respective pages of their wiki.)

  or
- Should we try to get the Akademy to repost them themselves (i.e. under the Akademy's name, or that of Akademy members)? (Again with attribution and backlinks)

  or
- Should we try to get the original question authors to repost their selected questions here and to get the Akademy to repost the corresponding answers?

(We probably cannot legally repost the questions and answers without explicit permissions, as the wiki states no license and as the scope would IMHO go beyond what's covered by quoting fair use rights.)

#### Important notice

Please refrain from reposting those questions and answers on Stack Exchange in full, until we have explicit permission to do so. Of course, feel free to cite and quote them (with proper attribution), as you would any other proprietary source.

Answer (score 2):

Those questions are asked by random Esperanto speakers, who have never released them under the licence CC BY-SA 3.0. I also asked some of those questions, and I have never explicitly transferred my copyright.

We probably can't find out who asked those questions, since they are posted anonymously.

Comment: It is true that without explicit transfer of copyrights, the asker [still owns his question](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/legal-issues-user-generated-content/#Avoiding_Issues_Around_Users8217_Intellectual_Property). But are you sure that the transfer has not taken place? The [_Regularo de Lingva Konsultejo de la Akademio de Esperanto_](http://akademio.info/akademio/index.php?title=Lingva_Konsultejo) says "[the Akademio] decidas ĉu necesas publikigi la respondon en la retpaĝaro de la konsultejo aŭ/kaj transsendi ĝin al la Esperanto-gazetaro kaj gravaj movadaj instancoj"

Comment: which I read as them being allowed to share the questions with (some) third-parties.

Comment: Nothing in that text is about copyright or licences. The asker only gives permission to AdE to republish the question, not permission to release it under a Creative Commons licence.

Comment: If the following English translation is correct, then I read it as the Akademio could decide to transmit the answer to important movement bodies (_decides whether it is necessary to publish the answer on the website of the consultancy and/or to transmit it to the Esperanto press and important movement bodies_). This means it's the Akademio to decide, and its decision is only about important movement bodies, which I don't think includes _Esperanto Language_.

Comment: That sentence doesn't say anything about the questions, though. I find it strange, if both the questions and the answers are posted by users.